# Is there a way to export rMaps output to image?

Tags: r, rmaps

I'm starting to work with rMaps (following [this example](http://lcolladotor.github.io/2014/02/26/excited-by-willingness-to-help-get-things-done/#.U_vWrKcR03t)), and it's a great package. I'd like to include the results in a document, either by exporting the result to a .jpeg, .png or other graphical format, or by rendering the output directly into a LaTeX document (using sweave or knitr). However, after searching a lot, I've found no way to do it.

So, the question is: Is there a (preferibly simple) way to export rMaps result (`ichoropleth`, `crosslet` and/or `Leaflet`) directly to an image file (or set of files)?

Comment: Do you want't to export the interactivity as well? Or just the map.                                                                            You seem to know a lot. At any rate my favorite sub part of    your example post to this question was this     https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps/issues/6

Comment: I can settle with exporting one frame of the interactivity... I'd like to include the resulting map in a printed document (or PDF file), so interactivity is not needed. Of course, it would be nice to export every frame of the interactive map into a file or image, but that would be an extra (it would be "a cherry on top of the cake" ;) )